# SQL Server inner join after Count and GroupBy

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to make an eCommerce web site. And at `ProductCategory` page I have to do a list about `Companies` that included by `Products`.

I have a `Product` table that contains:

```
ProductID
ProductName
...
MarkID
```

And I have a `Company` table that contains:

```
CompanyID
CompanyName
```

I want to mix them in a query.

After that code block,

```
SELECT 
   CompanyID, 
   count(CompanyID) as CompanyCount
FROM 
   Products 
GROUP by 
   CompanyID
```

I get this result:

```
CompanyID   CompanyCount
-------------------------
  1               2
  3               1
  4               4
```

after that I just want to inner join that with `CompanyName`

And want a result like this:

```
CompanyName CompanyCount
---------------------------
   1               2
   3               1
   4               4
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved without a subquery.

```
SELECT C.CompanyID, C.CompanyName, COUNT(*)
FROM Products P INNER JOIN Companies C ON P.CompanyId = C.CompanyID
GROUP BY C.CompanyID, C.CompanyName
```

Comment: I prefer the sub query. If selecting more columns from the company table it's a pain to add them to both places. Also some column datatypes can't be added to the group by. Also the plans can be better with the group by then join.

Answer (score 4):

With a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT CompanyID, count(CompanyID) as CompanyCount
    FROM Products 
    GROUP by CompanyID
) CompanyCounts
INNER JOIN Companies
on CompanyCounts.CompanyId = Companies.CompanyID
```

If you need this in more places, you may want to create a view for company count.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your first select as a subquery to join with Companies table:

`SELECT C.CompanyName, Q1.CompanyCount
FROM Companies C
JOIN (
SELECT CompanyID, count(CompanyID) as CompanyCount
  FROM Products 
 GROUP by CompanyID
) Q1
ON Q1.CompanyID = C.CompanyId`